# Clustering K-means algorithm for elongated data set

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have go question while programming K-means algorithm in Matlab. Why K-means algorithm not suitable for classifying elongated data set?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) question?

Answer (score -1):

In sort, draw some thick lines on a paper. Can you really represent each one with a single point? How would single points give information about orientation?

K-means assigns each datapoint to each *nearest* centroid. That is to say that for each centroid `c`, all points that their distance from  `c` is smaller (in comparison to all other centroids) will be assigned to `c`. And, since the surface of a (hyper)sphere is in fact, all points with distance less or equal to some value from a center, I think it is easy to see how resulted clusters tend to be spherical. (To be exact, kmeans practically creates a *Voronoi diagram* in the vector space)

Elongated clusters however, don't necessarily satisfy the requirement that all their points are closer to their "center of mass" than to some other cluster's center.

Answer (score -3):

It is difficult for you to choose a init cluster center point in elongated data set, but it has a powerful effect on the result.You may get different results when choose different points.

You will get only one result in this case when you choose 3 init points:

[image]

But it is different in elongated data set.

Comment: It's not more difficult to choose the initial points on elongated data.